# lighttpd set download speed for different files types

Tags: lighttpd

I am just wondering if I can setup bandwidth/download speed for different file types. Such as having 300kb/s for flv, mp4 video files, unlimited for image files, 500kb/s for pdf files etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use traffic shaping to do this for example...

```
$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "(.*)\.flv$" {
        server.kbytes-per-second = 300
    }
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "(.*)\.mp4$" {
        server.kbytes-per-second = 300
    }
    $HTTP["url"] =~ "(.*)\.pdf$" {
        server.kbytes-per-second = 500
    }
    server.document-root = "/var/www/example.com/wwwroot"
}
```

Documented here http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_trafficshaping

That said unless your under bandwidth restriction, this is seldom a good idea from a users point of view.